# Horizontal "masonry" type layout with variable row heights

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I am trying to create an image gallery using something similar to the infamous "masonry" layout. I have looked at many libraries and ways of doing this and none of them are exactly what I am looking for. All the images are different aspect ratios and have different widths and heights.

I want the layout to be similar to this image that I grabbed from this [site](https://css-tricks.com/piecing-together-approaches-for-a-css-masonry-layout/#is-horizontal-line-masonry-ok):

[image: Image Showing Idea of Intended Layout (with fixed heights)]

However, I want the heights of each row to be variable to account for the different image sizes, unlike the example above which has fixed heights. The gallery also needs to be constrained by the left and right sides of the container (in this case, the viewport). The images should not be cropped but can be made as big or small as necessary to fit as well as possible without gaps and to extend to the right side of the container. Images on the bottom row would be left justified. I built my own working version of this using flexbox and wrapping. This required a lot of trial and error and custom values for the heights of each row, when I feel like it would be a lot easier for code to just figure out the best order and layout of all the images and the correct heights.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

The kind of layout you're after is commonly called **masonry layout**. CSS already has a specification achieving this (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Masonry_Layout) but so far Firefox is the only browser that has support for it *behind a flag*. If you want to enable this experimental support, go to `about:config` in Firefox, and set `layout.css.grid-template-masonry-value.enabled` to `true`.

If you want to try that out, use

```
.container { 
  display: grid; 
  grid-template-columns: masonry; 
  gap: 15px;
}
```

Also compare https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_masonry and https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_grid-template-rows_masonry.

Comment: you should be the official stackoverflow masonry ambassador :D

Comment: I appreciate the answer! I included masonry in my question so I am aware of it and also read that it is flagged in Firefox. However, there are ways to make a vertical masonry layout without using this CSS property. Furthermore, this does not address what I was asking about automatic variable row heights.